# Call a c++ function from html

Tags: javascript, html, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

The requirement is to call a visual studio 2012 c++ function from a html page.On the onClick event of button the function should get executed.

Comment: Is the HTML page hosted by Internet Explorer?

Comment: it would probably be mozilla or chrome

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can do, take a look at [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dx3d2ftc.aspx) about.

You have to add a row like this in your c file:

```
STDMETHOD(OnClick)(IDispatch* pdispBody, VARIANT varColor)
```